# errors while translating registry checks from powershel to c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have this code in powershell which works perfectly and now I am trying to rewrite it in c#.

```
   $admin = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")

   $basePath = “HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription” 

    if (test-path $basePath){$vt = get-itemproperty $basepath |foreach-object {$_.EnableTranscripting}


     if ($vt -eq 1 -and $admin -eq $true){Remove-Item $basepath -Force -Recurse}elseif($vt -eq 1 -and $admin -eq $false){exit}};
```

Here is the c# code:

```
      using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Text;
      using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
      using System.Diagnostics;
      using System.Security.Principal;
      using Microsoft.Win32;

 public class Program
{

 static bool IsHighIntegrity()
    {
        // returns true if the current process is running with adminstrative privs in a high integrity context
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }


  static string GetReg()
    {
        string defaultkey = "";
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Powershell\\Transcription"))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                Object o = key.GetValue("");
                if (o != null)
                {
                    defaultkey = o.ToString();                                           
                }
            }
       } }

 

static void Main(){


 if (IsHighIntegrity())
        {

string RegPath = "Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Powershell\\Transcription";
string RegPath1 = "SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\PowerShell\\Transcription";
if (defaultkey == 1){

    try
        {
            Console.Write("[*] Attempting to delete registry tree: {0}... ", RegPath);
            Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(RegPath);
    Console.Write("[*] Attempting to delete registry tree: {0}... ", RegPath1);
    Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(RegPath1);
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FAILURE.");
            Console.WriteLine("Reason:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
}
        Console.WriteLine("[*] All Done.");
 }

        else
        {
if (defaultkey == 1){

Environment.Exit(1);

     }

            

     }

   }
 }
```

I get the following errors while trying to compile:

> test.cs(22,21): error CS0161: 'Program.GetReg()': not all code paths return a value
> test.cs(47,6): error CS0103: The name 'defaultkey' does not exist in the current context
> test.cs(69,6): error CS0103: The name 'defaultkey' does not exist in the current context

The errors are pretty verbose but after reading through literature such as:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Win32_Registry_GetValue_System_String_System_String_System_Object_

and stack overflow questions, I cannot figure out why I am not receiving a value.

All help appreciated

Comment: What is `GetReg()` returning? Where is it being used?

Comment: GetReg is to check if 1.) the key exists and if it does whether the key returns 1 or 0 to see if it is activated or not. Well that was what I was aiming for anyway... :)

Comment: Well, currently it's not returning anything when you've defined the return value as a string...

Comment: Bottom line, follow up on what the errors are actually telling you and try and fix those issues. The errors don't have anything to do with your call to `Program.GetReg()`